# How to make lodash sortBy not sort if values are equal

Tags: javascript, sorting, lodash

I am trying to chain a few lodash sortBy functions, but on the final sortBy I want to make it conditional.  I don't want to change the position in the array if the UTC is the same

code:

```
const events = _(arr).chain().sortBy((e) => {
    return e.event.json.QUERY.type
  }).sortBy((e) => {
    if (e.event.json.QUERY.type === 'ad') {
      return e.event.json.QUERY.metadata.ad.assetid;
    } else {
      return e.event.json.QUERY.metadata.content.assetid;
    }
  }).sortBy((e) => {
    return e.event.json.QUERY.utc;  // this is where I want a conditional but I don't know if that's possible with lodash
  }).value()
```

Answer (score 3):

The lodash `sortBy` method implements a stable sort, i.e. it wont swap elements when their sort key values are the same.

From the [documentation on `sortBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#sortBy):

> This method performs a stable sort, that is, it preserves the original sort order of equal elements.

Comment: Thank you.  I must have been console logging with my previous array and didn't realize the new array was actually doing what I wanted. Thanks!